# The fundamental theorem of calculus and function composition

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading Gong Sheng's [Concise Complex Analysis](https://www.amazon.co.uk/CONCISE-COMPLEX-ANALYSIS-REVISED-YOUHONG/dp/9812706933/ref=sr_1_1), where in Chapter 1 reviewing calculus, he says

> The fundamental theoren1 of calculus plays the most important role in
> calculus. There are two equivalent forms of this theorem:
>
> Theorem 1.1 (The Fundo,mental Theorem of Calculus) (differ-form)
> Suppose the function $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and
> $x\in [a,b]$, Let  $$\Phi(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$$ , $a\le x \le b$. Then
> $\Phi(x)$ is differentiable in $[a, b]$ and $\Phi'(x) = f(x)$,
> $d\Phi(x) = f(x)dx$. In  other words, if the integral of $f(x)$ is
> $\Phi(x)$, then the differential of $\Phi(x)$ is  $f(x)$.
>
> Theorem 1.2 (The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) (integral  form)
> Suppose $\Phi(x)$ is differentiable in $[a, b]$; and $d\Phi(x)/dx$ is
> equal to  a continuous function $f(x)$. Then
> $$\int_a^x f(t) dt = \Phi(x) - \Phi(a)$$
> , $(a\le x \le b)$ holds. In other words: If the
> differential of $\Phi(x)$ is $f(x)$, then the integral  of $f(x)$ is
> $\Phi(x)$.
>
> By this theorem, finding the integral is the inverse operation of
> finding  the differential of a function, and properties of
> differentials correspond to  properties of integrals. For instance:
>
> $$\frac{d(f(x)\pm g(x))}{dx}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}\pm\frac{d  g(x)}{dx}$$
>
> corresponds to
>
> $$\int (f(x)\pm g(x))dx = \int f(x) dx \pm \int g(x) dx$$ ; and
>
> $$\frac{d}{dx}(fg) = f \frac{dg}{dx}+\frac{df}{dx} g$$
>
> corresponds to  $$\int fg' dx = fg - \int gf' dx$$

So far so good... then he mentions that given $y=g(x)$

> $$\frac{d f(g(x))}{dx} = \frac{df}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$$
>
> corresponds to  $$\int f(g(x))g'(x) dx = \int f(y) dy$$

I couldn't figure out, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and the differential form $\frac{d f(g(x))}{dx} = \frac{df}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$, how could one derive the integral form $\int f(g(x))g'(x) dx = \int f(y) dy$, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $F$ is an anti-derivative of $f$. Then the function $F \circ g$ will have the anti-derivative $(F' \circ g) \cdot g' = (f \circ g) \cdot g'$ by the chain rule. That is, the function $h(x) = F(g(x))$ will have derivative $h'(x) = f(g(x)) g'(x)$.

Thus, if we can find an anti-derivative of $f$, we can use this anti-derivative to find an anti-derivative of $f(g(x)) g'(x)$. This is what $u$-substitution is all about.

Comment: why "$F \circ g$ will have the anti-derivative $(F' \circ g) \cdot g' = (f \circ g) \cdot g'$ by the chain rule"?

Comment: Because by the chain rule, $\frac{d}{dx} F(g(x)) = F'(g(x)) g'(x) = f(g(x)) g'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{d}{dx}\Phi(g(x))=f(g(x))g'(x)$, we have
$$\int_a^bf(g(x))g'(x)dx=\Phi(g(b))-\Phi(g(a))=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)dx$$